# Rotation of a shape in HTML5

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I want to create an array that is having an angle of this.dAngle with the horizontal line. This is my code of the function that creates the arrow.

```
var offset;

    if (this.dLength < 10) offset = this.dLength;
    else offset = Math.min(this.dLength * 0.1, 10);

    this.shape = new createjs.Shape();

    //rotation

    this.canvasId = this.stage.canvas.id;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasId);
    if(this.canvas) {
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");    
    }
    if(this.ctx) {
        console.log('rotate');
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.rotate(this.dAngle);
    }

    this.canvasId = this.stage.canvas.id;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasId);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.shape.graphics.clear();
    this.shape.graphics.beginStroke("black");

    this.shape.graphics.moveTo(0, 50);
    this.shape.graphics.lineTo(this.dLength, 50);

    this.shape.graphics.moveTo((this.dLength - offset), 50+(offset / 2));
    this.shape.graphics.lineTo(this.dLength, 50);
    this.shape.graphics.lineTo((this.dLength - offset), 50+(-offset / 2));

    this.ctx.restore();
```

But the rotation is not being done. Any solutions?

Comment: you're using both the canvas directly and through easeljs, when easeljs's Shape has a rotation poperty . Choose your weapon ! ;-)

Comment: yes i solved it by creating the shape using easel and then using the rotation property.